# How to get the prediction results in cross validation in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn cross-validation for binary classification problem. My code looks as follows.

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
y = iris.target

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf=RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 0, class_weight="balanced")

from sklearn.model_selection cross_val_score, cross_validate
cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=10, scoring = 'accuracy')
```

The `cross_val_score` only outputs the accurary of each fold in cross validation. However, I want to get the class label that my classifier assigned for each data point in `X`.

For instance, I am expecting an output as follows.

```
X, predicted_label
x1, 0
x2, 1
x3, 0
x4, 1
x5, 1
x6, 1
.........
```

I know that there is function called `predict_proba` in sklearn. However, it only outputs the probability. In my situation, I want the predicted class label.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict` ([source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict))

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict

diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()

X = diabetes.data[:150]
y = diabetes.target[:150]

lasso = linear_model.Lasso()
y_pred = cross_val_predict(lasso, X, y, cv=3)

print(y_pred)
```

```
[174.26933996 117.6539241  164.60228641 155.65049088 132.68647979
 128.49511245 120.76146877 141.069413   164.18904498 182.37394949]
```

It works with classification too, of course.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Just wondering whether the output comes in the order of the data points in X? Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: I guess, otherwise the entire thing wouldn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

A late answer, but it can help other beginners (like me). Below, an example of how to get real and predicted values (in this case, classes) from cross validation using KFold, cross_val_score and cross_val_predict from Sklearn:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict, KFold, cross_val_score
iris = datasets.load_iris()
x = iris.data
y = iris.target
model_ = SVC()

kf = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=43, shuffle=True)
pred = cross_val_predict(model_, x, y, cv=kf)
scores = cross_val_score(model_, x, y, cv=kf)

print([f'pred train: {pred[i]}' for i, j in kf.split(x, y)])
print([f'pred test: {pred[j]}' for i, j in kf.split(x, y)], end='\n\n')

print([f'real train: {y[i]}' for i, j in kf.split(x, y)])
print([f'real test: {y[j]}' for i, j in kf.split(x, y)], end='\n\n')

print([f'acc-{i}: {round(score*100,2)}' for i,score in zip(range(1,11), scores)])
```

The result:

```
['pred train: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1\n 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2\n 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'pred train: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1\n 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2\n 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'pred train: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1\n 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2\n 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'pred train: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1\n 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2\n 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'pred train: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2\n 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2\n 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'pred train: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1\n 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2\n 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'pred train: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2\n 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2\n 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'pred train: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1\n 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2\n 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'pred train: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1\n 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2\n 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'pred train: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1\n 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2\n 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]']
['pred test: [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1]', 'pred test: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 2 2 1 2]', 'pred test: [0 0 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2]', 'pred test: [0 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 2]', 'pred test: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2]', 'pred test: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2]', 'pred test: [0 0 0 0 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'pred test: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2]', 'pred test: [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'pred test: [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2]']

['real train: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1\n 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2\n 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'real train: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1\n 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2\n 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'real train: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1\n 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2\n 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'real train: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1\n 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2\n 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'real train: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1\n 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2\n 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'real train: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1\n 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2\n 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'real train: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1\n 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2\n 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'real train: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1\n 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2\n 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'real train: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1\n 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2\n 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'real train: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1\n 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2\n 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]']
['real test: [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2]', 'real test: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 2 2 2 2]', 'real test: [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2]', 'real test: [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2]', 'real test: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2]', 'real test: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2]', 'real test: [0 0 0 0 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'real test: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2]', 'real test: [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2]', 'real test: [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2]']

['acc-1: 93.33', 'acc-2: 93.33', 'acc-3: 93.33', 'acc-4: 80.0', 'acc-5: 100.0', 'acc-6: 100.0', 'acc-7: 100.0', 'acc-8: 100.0', 'acc-9: 100.0', 'acc-10: 100.0']
```